# Can I get Kronos-Haskell to use my Haskell platform?

Tags: haskell, configuration, haskell-platform

[Kronos-Haskell](http://www.kronosnotebook.com/haskell) installs as a self-contained application and can exist (as near as I can tell) alongside an installation of the [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) without any issues or interactions. This is a nice feature, however I would like to use a current version of Haskell, along with some additional packages I've installed to the Haskell Platform.

Is there a way to get Kronos-Haskell to use my installation of the Haskell Platform?

Answer (score 2):

You can build IHaskell yourself using this recipe from the [README](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/blob/master/README.md):

```
git clone http://www.github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell
cd IHaskell
./macos-install.sh
```

Note - it might take a while as there are a ton of dependencies.

Comment: This looks promising. Can you elaborate a bit: I've got a current Python (2.7) and IPython installation, maintained with Homebrew, and I have the latest GHC and Cabal. If I understand correctly, all I need to do is (1) [`brew install zeromq`](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/blob/master/README.md#install-zeromq), (2) [`cabal install happy cpphs`](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/blob/master/README.md#install-haskell-tools) and (3) [`cabal install ihaskell --reorder-goals`](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/blob/master/README.md#build-ihaskell). Is that correct?

Comment: And if I go down that path, Kronos-Haskell is unaffected (it's self-contained and and could in fact be deleted altogether) right?

Comment: And perhaps more importantly: [will I be able to continue to use IPython and IPython Notebooks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32055302/656912) (and how do I switch between the two languages)?